# IndexOutOfBoundsException after row inserted, table sorted, then row deleted

Tags: java, swing

In a previous question ([Convert modelRowIndex to viewRowIndex for sorted JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830810/convert-modelrowindex-to-viewrowindex-for-sorted-jtable#16831518)) I indicated that I was trying to create a "simple" JTable that used a TableModel to tie an ArrayList to a JTable using a TableModel.  My goal was - and still is - to retain all of java's built-in JTable functionality that allows cell editing, row sorting, and column rearranging.  Thanks to your help, that functionality now works.

I'm now trying to add the ability to Insert and Delete table rows.  The (updated) example I provide here works ... EXCEPT ... under a certain sequence of operations, an "IndexOutOfBoundsException" is thrown.  Here's my code:

```
package tableexample;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public final class TableExample extends JFrame {

        List<REItem> REList;
        JTable tblREList;
        JButton btnAddInsertRE, btnDeleteRE;
        JScrollPane spMain;
        JFrame frame;
        Container pane;

    public TableExample() {
        // create and populate the ArrayList
        REList = new ArrayList<>();
        REList.add(new REItem("Template1", "Comment1"));
        REList.add(new REItem("Template2", "Comment2"));
        RETableModel retm = new RETableModel(REList);  // Connect the List to the TableModel
        // create GUI components
        frame = new JFrame ("Table Example");
        btnAddInsertRE = new JButton("Add/Insert");
        btnDeleteRE = new JButton("Delete");
        tblREList = new JTable(retm); 
        tblREList.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        spMain = new JScrollPane(tblREList);
        // add button ActionListeners
        btnAddInsertRE.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> { btnAddInsertREActionPerformed(evt); });
        btnDeleteRE.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> { btnDeleteREActionPerformed(evt); });
        // place GUI components and make the GUI visible
        pane = frame.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout (null);        
        pane.add(btnAddInsertRE);
        pane.add(btnDeleteRE);
        pane.add(spMain);
        btnAddInsertRE.setBounds (10, 10, 100, 25);
        btnDeleteRE.setBounds (120, 10, 100, 25);
        spMain.setBounds (10, 45, spMain.getPreferredSize().width, spMain.getPreferredSize().height);
        frame.setSize(spMain.getWidth() + 40, spMain.getHeight() + 95);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } // end TableExample constructor

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            TableExample notUsed = new TableExample();
        });
    } //end main

    private void btnAddInsertREActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // Add a FileSelection object to the ArrayList
        int r = tblREList.getSelectedRow();                         // get row selection, if any
        if (r < 0) {                                                // no row selected
            REList.add(new REItem("NewTemplate", "NewComment"));    //   append new item to end
            r = REList.size()-1;                                    //   get index to new item
        } else {                                                    // else no row selected
            REList.add(r, new REItem("NewTemplate", "NewComment")); //   insert above selected row
        }                                                           // row selected or not
        spMain.setViewportView(tblREList);                          // repaint the updated table
        tblREList.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(r, r);   // select the new row
    }                                            

    private void btnDeleteREActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        int[] selRows = tblREList.getSelectedRows();                // see if any rows are selected
        if (selRows.length>0) {                                     // at least one row is selected
            for (int r=selRows.length-1; r>=0; r--) {               //   delete each row, from the bottom up,
                REList.remove(r);                                   //     so that indexes are correct and
            }                                                       //       don't change with each delete
            tblREList.clearSelection();                             // clear the row selection data
            spMain.setViewportView(tblREList);                      // repaint the updated table
        } else {                                                    // else no row(s) selected
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Must select at least one item to delete");
        }                                                           // no row selected
    } // end btnDeleteREActionPerformed

    public final class REItem {
        String template;
        String comment;

        public REItem(String tmp, String cmt) {
            this.template = tmp;
            this.comment = cmt;
        }
    } // end class REItem

    public class RETableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<REItem> reList = new ArrayList();
        private final String[] columnNames = { "Template", "Comment" };

        public RETableModel(List<REItem> list){
             this.reList = list;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column){
             return columnNames[column];
        }

        @Override     
        public int getRowCount() {
            return reList.size();
        }

        @Override        
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length; 
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0: return reList.get(row).template;
                case 1: return reList.get(row).comment;
               }
               return null; // default case
       }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column){
            switch (column){
                case 0: return String.class;
                case 1: return String.class;
            }
            return null; // default case
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0: reList.get(row).template = value.toString(); break;
                case 1: reList.get(row).comment = value.toString(); break;
               }
            // uncommenting the below often causes IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range exception
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, column); 
        } // end setValueAt

    } // end RETableModel

} // end class TableExample
```

The problem can be reproduced as follows: Run the above example, click the "Add/Insert" button to append a new row to the table, click either column header to re-sort the table, then click the "Delete" button:  An "IndexOutOfBoundsException" is thrown, indicating that the "row" index specified by the TableModel's getValueAt method is flawed.

I assume the issue is related to the need for my TableModel.getValueAt (and maybe .setValueAt ???) method(s) to convert between TableModel column indexes and View column indexes but, for the life of me, I can't figure out how or where to make the conversion.  Morevover, this question ([Convert modelRowIndex to viewRowIndex for sorted JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830810/convert-modelrowindex-to-viewrowindex-for-sorted-jtable#16831518)) indicates that a conversion between TableModel and View row-indexes is needed, AND that table re-sorting MUST occur before the index conversion is done.

Try as I might, I cannot figure out how to make the conversion and/or how to make sure that conversion happens AFTER the table is updated and re-sorted.  Do I need a Listener?  If so, what should it look like?

Can you provide some clarification and help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. This is a Java convention and it messes with the formatting of the code you post making your code hard to read. Fix your variables and follow Java conventions.

The ArrayList should only be used to initially add data to the model.

After that updates should be done to the TableModel, not the ArrayList. So you need to add methods to your TableModel like `addREItem(...)` and `removeREItem(...)`.

See [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step example of how to build a custom TableModel for a given object, including how the code the add???(...) and remove???(...) method.

And if you want to remove selected rows from the table then check out: [How to delete multiple rows from JTable , database at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227729/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-from-jtable-database-at-a-time/38228994#38228994) for a working examples that shows how this can be done using the remove???(...) method.

Comment: Did everything you suggested.  All working now. :-)  Thanks for the excellent links regarding RowTableModel and deleting multiple items.   But the RowTableModel tip indicates that "instead of manually creating a TableModel from scratch every time ... you can use the RowTableModel ... to implement all the functionality (except get/setValueAt).  Is that suggesting that it would be simpler for me to extend RowTableModel rather than AbstractTableModel?  Then I'd have to provide only the get/setValueAt methods unique to my list objects?

Comment: `Is that suggesting that it would be simpler for me to extend RowTableModel rather than AbstractTableModel?` - you should always understand the basics of creating your own TableModel first. The process you have gone through helps with this. But now in the future you may find you keep repeating the same steps every time you need a new custom TableModel. The RowTableModel is my way of simplifying the process in the future. That is 90% of the code is common and only a few methods need to be customized. So there is less chance of error and it saves time.

Comment: So next time you need a custom model, try extending from RowTableModel and then decide which approach you like best. The idea of the link is to give you a choice.  The RowTableModel has lots of extra functionality that you may not need. The RowTableModeL is more complex to understand because of the usage of Generics. I wrote the code as a learning tool to better understand Generics.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  Most appreciated was your initial statement that "The ArrayList should only be used to initially add data to the model. After that updates should be done to the TableModel, not the ArrayList."  While in hindsight that seems obvious, I have not, in all my prior research, seen it stated clearly like that.  Your advice regarding the TableModel - learning the basics first, then expanding to advanced techniques - is also well taken and much appreciated.